# pip3 error on installing packages on ubuntu 18.04 - Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1"

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to install the `poster` package using the:
`pip3 install poster` and it gave me the `python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1`

`pip` works with no problem.

I have tried other solutions I've found on Stackoverflow or other places such as:

1- `pip install --upgrade setuptools`  <-- didn't solve the problem

2- `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools`  <-- didn't solve the problem

3- `easy_install distribute`
and then
`pip install --upgrade distribute`  #--> didn't solve the problem (`easy install` is [deprecated](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html))

My system : Ubuntu 18.04 - Python 3.6.8

error:

```py
pip3 install poster==0.8.1
Collecting poster==0.8.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/dc/0683a458d21c3d561ab2f71b4fcdd812bf04e55c54e560b0854cea95610e/poster-0.8.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-t1p0qepc/poster/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
        import poster
      File "/tmp/pip-build-t1p0qepc/poster/poster/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
        import poster.streaminghttp
      File "/tmp/pip-build-t1p0qepc/poster/poster/streaminghttp.py", line 61
        print "send:", repr(value)
                    ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-t1p0qepc/poster/
```

Answer (score 1):

https://pypi.org/project/poster/

The last release: Apr 16, 2011.

[Supported Python versions](https://pypi.org/project/poster/#files): 2.4 to 2.7.

This is an outdated and abandoned Python2-only project.

Comment: ooops!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem solved by entering pip command with sudo :

```
sudo pip install package-name
```

Comment: `sudo pip install` is usually an antipattern. Don't mix PyPI with system packages.